# Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found

Tags: php, linux, http, centos

Whilst trying to make this request I have this error.

I have tried to run "`sudo pecl install pecl_http`" but always fails.

```
Could not find curl/curl.h
```

After I have tired(yum instead of apt-get because I am running centOS):

```
sudo yum install libcurl4-gnults-dev
```

But this sends:

```
No package libcurl4-gnutls-dev avaliable Error: Nothing to do.
```

Any more ideas guys I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Did some googling looks like

`curl-devel` is the name of package not `libcurl4-gnults-dev`

so

```
sudo yum install curl-devel
```

Should do.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I googled for some answers. For anyone else who runs into this issue I used "sudo yum install curl-devel" and worked perfectly thanks. Now I will restart and retry. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, install pear:

```
yum install php-pear
```

You may need to install these packages for dependencies:

```
yum install zlibc
yum install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

add `"extension=http.so"` to php.ini and restart Apache:

`service httpd restart`